# Still having trouble with mapping using SQLCMD

Tags: sqlcmd

I am trying to map MyDatabase as shown below. It works fine in SMS but my SQLCMD code always maps to 'master.

[image]

This works fine in SMS.

```
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
CREATE USER [TEST\MyUser] FOR LOGIN [TEST\MyUser]
GO
USE [MyDatabase]
GO
EXEC sp_addrolemember N'MyUser', N'TEST\MyUser'
```

How do I implement it in SQLCMD?  I have tried:

```
SQLCMD.exe -E -S (local) -Q "USE [MyDatabase]"
SQLCMD.exe -E -S (local) -Q "CREATE USER [TEST\MyUser] FOR LOGIN \TEST\MyUser]"
SQLCMD.exe -E -S (local) -Q "USE [MyDatabase]"
SQLCMD.exe -E -S (local) -Q "EXEC sp_addrolemember N'MyUser', N'TEST\MyUser'"
```

Answer (score 2):

Specify the database on the command line with the `-d` switch.  The database is reset to the user's default (in this case, `master`) on each statement otherwise.  So, you want something like:

```
sqlcmd -S (local) -d MyDatabase -E -Q "CREATE USER [TEXT\MyUser] FOR LOGIN [TEST\MyUser]"
sqlcmd -S (local) -d MyDatabase -E -Q "EXEC sp_addrolemember N'MyUser', N'TEST\MyUser'"
```